# how to get rid of NaN after up-resample the dataframe using last?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, resampling

I up-sampled my dataframe using the `resample` function from `pandas`. Initialy I had 0 NaNs, but after sampling, I have 317 NaNs.

My code is the following:

`df= df.resample("200s").agg(func="last")`

Is there any way to repair(fill NaNs) the dataframe by modifying the code above or should I iterate again in order to get over NaNs? I would like to still keep the "last" value, as in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the `.ffill()` function of pandas. This is made for [upsampling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.ffill.html?highlight=ffill#pandas.core.resample.Resampler.ffill).

```
df= df.resample("200s").ffill()
```

An alternative is also pandas `.fillna()` function with method 'ffill'.

```
df= df.resample("200s").sum().fillna(method='ffill')`
```

Check the [dokumentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) for more information.